# How to determine the length of mp3/wav file played by mpg321

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-b+

Hi guys i would like to ask how can i get the length of the mp3/wav file using python codes? Right now i have 1 button connected to GPIO, after i press the button the mp3 file will play. Now i want to get also the length of mp3 file, if i press the button the mp3 file will play and also display the length of the file that play... Here`s my code:

```
import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmod(GPIO.BCM)
PGIO.setup(23,GPIO.IN)

while True:

if (GPIO.input(23) == True):
     os.system('mpg321 /media/usb/dropped.mp3 -q &')
     print(" THE LENGTH OF THE MP3 FILE THAT PLAYED ")

sleep(1.0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the accepted answer to this Stack Exchange [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037826/finding-the-length-of-an-mp3-file) and modified for Python 3

Install mutagen:

```
sudo pip3 install mutagen
```

Then add this to your code:

```
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
audio = MP3("/media/usb/dropped.mp3")
print(audio.info.length)
```

This will return the length in seconds.

Comment: note: mutagen currently has no support for wav files though https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen/issues/207